# How to display ebay product listing in our site i have appid given by ebay

Tags: ebay-api

How to display ebay product listing in our site, I have appid given by ebay.

I  also want to display products from flipkart amazon etc. Is it possible with api or without it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen that you are using sandbox AppID with production $endpoint uri.

Use production AppId.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/howto/index.html

Complete tutorial explaining API usage with filter keys.
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/howto/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML.zip

Comment: Thnax.. shyam ..My current appid will be work or i need to new register??  for production ??.

Comment: i Have used this url to get xml format price list with my appid so what's worng with this plz help ..
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&SECURITY-APPNAME=ARt8f00d1-a67f-406d-8f9e-d65fb361eb2&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&productId.@type=UPC&productId=024543611363&itemFilter%280%29.name=Condition&itemFilter%280%29.value=New&itemFilter%281%29.name=ListingType&itemFilter%281%29.value=FixedPrice&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest

Comment: use production appID , may be currently you are using sandbox appid.

Comment: if your query is solved, mark it as solved. and you can upvote also.

Comment: Thanx bro it's working..U save my day :) thnx